# Install SSH Server or other terminal viewer for HTC X one

Tags: htc-one-x, ssh

I'm trying to set a SSH server in order to execute and download and upload files into my HTC One X. I tried Dropbear. and Dropbear 2 but they both failed.

Can I do it without rooting my htc?

Guy

Comment: Without root, you cannot use the default SSHD port (22) -- so the app needs to use a port > 1000 (usually 2222 to easily remember and associate it with SSH). You have to consider that client-side as well, and pass that port. From command-line, this is e.g. done using the parameter `-p 2222`. Have you done that? Maybe it only failed because you missed that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QuickSSHd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd&hl=cs) works on rooted and non-rooted phones. There are some limitations on non-rooted phones (running on port 2222 instead of 22, etc.), but other than this, I have yet to see any problem with it on any device (tested from 1.6 through 2.1 to 4.1). Costs approx. US$1.5

Comment: [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sshserver&hl=en) is a good free option as well. It also has a Pro version if you want to allow more than 3 active connections at a time.